# Chrome having different Breakpoint Measures

Tags: html, visual-studio, google-chrome, sass, breakpoints

I'm doing RWD right now and I have some problem with Chrome/VSC/or I don't know. Why there is the difference between SCSS and Chrome measures? My breakpoint is set in SCSS at 800px and in Chrome it is 640px, why? How to fix it?

[image: You can see here, difference of 140px]

Comment: Can you try changing `@media screen and` to just `@media`? This will properly use the width of the browser instead of the screen.

Comment: I tried it, but doesn't work. Any ideas more to fix it? It is misleading.

Comment: Also, you need to target the specific element in your css. You just have css inside of a media query. Unless that media query is nested within another CSS rule, try changing that too.

Comment: Well, I tested it on clear boilerPlate and still it is the different, I don't know why. 

https://ufile.io/88hwh

Answer (score 0):

The page size indicator doesn't take zoom level into account. Or you could say that it's in screen pixels instead of CSS pixels. Compare `innerWidth` and `outerWidth`.

Reset your zoom level to 100%, or multiply your target width by the zoom level to find the right value.

Or turn on the device toolbar and just click on the media queries to set the size to exactly that value.

Unfortunately, if you really want to be testing at 80% zoom, these tools don't work so well.

Comment: Thanks, I have downloaded Viewport Dimensions extention to google chrome and it works tho.